# How to move the input field which answer show up

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this code that auto sizing program. 
https://jsfiddle.net/blueink/ryom93p5/12/
it works good. I would like to change layout as Horizon. For example When user type number at G input field. I would like to display the answer next to it. like horizon. I'm wondering Can it give ID as name for the boxes and move whatever I would like to move?

```
jQuery(function($){
  $('input','.hsc').keyup(function(){
    var numG = $('input:eq(0)','.hsc').val();
    var numF = $('input:eq(1)','.hsc').val();
    var numE = $('input:eq(2)','.hsc').val();
    var numD = $('input:eq(3)','.hsc').val();
    var numC1 = $('input:eq(4)','.hsc').val();   
    var numC = $('input:eq(5)','.hsc').val();   
    var numA = $('input:eq(6)','.hsc').val();     
    numG = parseFloat(numG);
    numF = parseFloat(numF);
    numE = parseFloat(numE);
    numD = parseFloat(numD);
    numC1 = parseFloat(numC1);
    numC = parseFloat(numC);
    numA = parseFloat(numA);

var sta="";

if (15.0 <= numA && numA <= 18.0) {
sta += "SSサイズ ";
}
if (16.0 <= numA && numA <= 19.0) {
sta += "Sサイズ ";
}

if (17.0 <= numA && numA <= 20.0) {
sta += "Mサイズ ";
}

if (19.0 <= numA && numA <= 22.0) {
sta += "Lサイズ ";
}

if (20.0 <= numA && numA <= 23.0) {
sta += "LLサイズ ";
}

if (22.0 <= numA && numA <= 25.0) {
sta += "3Lサイズ ";
}

if (24.0 <= numA && numA <= 27.0) {
sta += "4Lサイズ ";
}
document.getElementById( "a" ).value = sta;



  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for id **A** as follows :

```
jQuery(function($){

  $('input','.hsc').keyup(function(){
     setTimeout(function(){
    var numA = $("#a").val(); 
    numA = parseFloat(numA);



  var sta="";
  var flag = 0;
  if (15.0 <= numA && numA <= 18.0) {

  flag = 1;
  sta = "SSサイズ ";
  }
  if (16.0 <= numA && numA <= 19.0) {
  flag = 1;
  sta = "Sサイズ ";
  }

  if (17.0 <= numA && numA <= 20.0) {
  flag = 1;
  sta = "Mサイズ ";
  }

  if (19.0 <= numA && numA <= 22.0) {
  flag = 1;
  sta = "Lサイズ ";
  }

  if (20.0 <= numA && numA <= 23.0) {
  flag = 1;
  sta = "LLサイズ ";
  }

  if (22.0 <= numA && numA <= 25.0) {
  flag = 1;
  sta = "3Lサイズ ";
  }

  if (24.0 <= numA && numA <= 27.0) {
  flag = 1;
  sta = "4Lサイズ ";
  }
  setTimeout(function(){
    if(flag == 1){
    $("#a").val(sta);
    }else{
    $("#a").val('');
    }

  }, 100);


  }, 1000);
  });

});
```

Do likewise code for other ids.
Thank you.

Comment: Dear @Ritesh Dhoke Thank you for answering me. I appreciate your help. Do me a favor could you teach me HTML code too? Actually I type number at A box but answer doesn't show up.

Comment: I did HTML code like this . Is this wrong write? <input type="text" class="form-control" id="#a">

Comment: Please correct your id.you specified # in id.please correct by following code.
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="a">

Comment: Dear @Ritesh Dhoke Thank you for your help. I appreciate a lot. Actually It still doesn't show up. Could you look my code ? https://jsfiddle.net/blueink/ryom93p5/19/    I change my code as you told me.

Comment: Dear @Ritesh Dhoke Amazing! Thank you! That's perfect! I appreciate all of your help! Thank you so much!